# How to return valid server URL downloadable path instead of JSON return response in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller function which return the response

```
return response()->json($mysqlpath->generatefile());
```

This returns me a response like this:

```
"\/home\/vagrant\/code\/laravel\/database\/sqls\/laravel mysql 2018-07-17 14-16-58 6ea8a0de2ba3.sql"
```

How to return a server downloadable path?

Comment: you only want get the full file url ? try this: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$url = Storage::url('file.jpg');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be available under using 
`$response->download(url);`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-downloads

Comment: this starts downloading the file directly. Can I just show a valid path?

Comment: return $mysqlpath->generatefile())

Comment: this showns /home/vagrant/code/laravel/database/sqls/laravel mysql 2018-07-17 14-49-14 6ea8a0de2ba3abda4d.sql which is not a downloadable link.

Comment: so do something like return view('viewname, ')->with('url',  mysqlpath->generatefile()); and create the view and use the variable url within it. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views